# Page returning same results even though the results are different each time. (Node, puppeteer, cheerio)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

Im scraping a dynamic website, which doesn't instantly load a list full of items.
I'm waiting until that content loads then i'm getting the pagination list and extracting the last items value for the page count.

once this is done i'm using a for loop to go through this website x amount of times based on the page count for that list of items.

once the first loop is complete and the data is gathered... i click the next button to move on to the next page, i await the data to change, then go back through the for loop to gather the new data in that list.

For some reason, the results returned is the same for each page, even though they're not the same, and i can see with using headless: false that the data is in-fact changing so why isn't it returning that new data?

`

```
try {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
        {
            headless: false
        }
    );

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
    }).catch((err) => console.log("error loading url", err));

    await page.waitForSelector(selector);

    const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return {
            html: document.documentElement.innerHTML,
        }

    });

    const $ = cheerio.load(pageData.html);

    for (let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {

        await page.waitForSelector(selector);

        $('.itemDivWrapper > div').each(async (i, g) => {
            let itemName = $(g).find('a > div > h3').text();
            console.log(itemName);
        });

        await Promise.all([
            page.$eval('div.itemList > nav > ul > li.nextButton > a', element =>
                element.click()
            ),
            await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
        ]);
    }


    await browser.close();

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

`

Maybe i'm just doing something silly wrong :'D and fresh eyes are needed :D.

Expect each loop to provide the new page data, which 100% showed before it tried to get that data. but returns the same values each time.

Comment: You're loading the data into cheerio before the for loop, so even if the page gets refreshed the data in $ cheerio remains about the previous page

Comment: @riskylast thank you so much! this worked. Do you want to put that as an answer so i can choose it for you? :)

Comment: Puppeteer already has selectors that work on the live website. Why not just use those [rather than Cheerio](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer)? What's the point of using `await` inside a `Promise.all()`? This makes the `Promise.all` completely superfluous.